# How to access data from Position Independent Code (PIC) in ARM Assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

I am using the GCC options `-mpic-data-is-text-relative` and  `-fpic` to generate position independent code. This works fine for my C code.

But I also have assembly code that needs to use PIC. The problem is I cannot find an example on how to achieve this. Are there some ARM GCC assembly keywords, do I need to set up my own GOT table or are there any neat tricks?

I'm trying to reach a variable from my code using PIC:

```
   .section .data @HWA_SWI_HND_DATA, "w"
hwa_ext_reset_hnd:
   .word 0x00000000

   .section .text @HWA_SWI_HND_CODE, "x"
   .code 32

   .list

   .global hwa_reset_cb_attach
hwa_reset_cb_attach:
   ldr r1, =hwa_ext_reset_hnd
   str r0, [r1]
   bx lr
```

As seen above in the `ldr r1, =hwa_ext_reset_hnd` call I want this address fetch to be PIC.

Comment: Simplest is to use `gcc -S` to compile a test C code and see what the compiler does.

Comment: If it can't encode the operand as an immediate or emit a `movw`/`movt` pair, the `ldr=` pseudo-op should assemble to a PC-relative load from the nearest literal pool, thus should be position-independent anyway. What does this look like once you assemble it and disassemble the result?

Comment: Jester: The compiler adds a look up table/relative offset. I would like to know a smart trick so I don't need to do this manually.

Comment: Notlikethat: for me ldr = uses an absolute address.

Comment: Oh I see, it's that the constant being _loaded_ is the absolute address, even if the `ldr=` itself is position-independent.

Comment: It is bare metal. I tried your suggestion but got "Error: constant expression expected -- `ldr r1,=hwa_ext_reset_hnd-.'"

Comment: I used `label: .word hwa_ext_reset_hnd-.+4'` and then `ldr r2, label; add pc,r2,pc`. Worked like a charm, can you write an answer or should I answer my own question?

Comment: I've changed it slightly and did like this, any comments? 
`label: .word hwa_ext_reset_hnd-.` and then `adr r0, label; ldr r1, label; add r0, r0, r1`. Now r0 will contain the correct address to the variable in the .data section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Elf DATA follows text and the offset to data can be known at link time. You need to add the PC to an offset between known location and data to access the data. See [ARM ELF](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0044e/IHI0044E_aaelf.pdf) and [Linkers and loader chp8 by John Levine](ftp://ftp.iecc.com/pub/linker/linker08.ps.gz).

Obviously, if this is hosted by an OS and loader, you will need to use the conventions of the platform.  The following is written for a *bare metal* system or places where you have the option to choose.

For example,

```
   .global hwa_reset_cb_attach
hwa_reset_cb_attach:
   adr r2, 1f                ; pc relative value of label '1'
   ldr r1, [r2]              ; offset between label and data to r1
   add r1, r1, r2            ; pc relative '1' label + offset there
   str r0, [r1]              ; store to corrected address.
   bx lr
1: .word hwa_ext_reset_hnd-. ; offset from here to data fixed at link.
```

This works for PIC code with data following immediately.  If you have many occurrences, you can create a macro to access the data.  If there are a lot of references, it maybe easier to keep a register loaded with the beginning of the *.data* section.  The *static base* with the compiler options `-msingle-pic-base` and `-mpic-register=`*reg*; *static base* is typically `r9`.  So the load time start of data is put in `r9` once and only use `str rx,[r9, #hwa_ext_reset-start_of_data]`.  This is a tactic used by *u-boot* and you can even *relocate* the data sections (moving from iram to SDRAM, etc).  However, it consumes an extra register.

Answer (score 2):

If the `.text` section on your bare metal system is writable, the simplest thing would be to move the variable to the `.text` section. You can then use LDR/STR/ADR to access the data directly using PC relative addressing:

```
   .section .text @HWA_SWI_HND_CODE, "xw"
   .code 32

hwa_ext_reset_hnd:
   .word 0x00000000

   .global hwa_reset_cb_attach
hwa_reset_cb_attach:
   str r0, hwa_ext_reset_hnd
   bx lr
```

Note that the `hwa_ext_reset_hnd` not only has to be defined in the same section, it need to be defined in the same assembly file so the assembler can figure out the PC relative offset.

If your text section isn't writable then you can still use PC relative addressing to simply things:

```
hwa_reset_cb_attach:
    ldr r1, _offset_hwa_ext_reset_hnd
_base_hwa_ext_reset_hnd:
    str r0, [pc, r1]
    bx lr

_offset_hwa_ext_reset_hnd:
    .word hwa_ext_reset_hnd - (_base_hwa_ext_reset_hnd + 8)
```