# avoiding text relocations when mixing c/c++ and assembly in a .so

Tags: android, c++, c, assembly, arm

I am trying to remove all text relocations from an .so that mixes c, c++ and assembly.  For c/c++ -fpic takes care of PIC.

On Android ARM target, we are able to call exported asm functions from c/c++ without causing text relocations.  But in our implementation we have arrays of data that must be accessible from both C++ and assembly.  On C++ it's a plain old array i.e. `extern "C" { __declspec(align(32)) int16_t myarray[256]; }` and on asm side we use `.global myarray`.

The second we use such a symbol in asm side we see text relocation in the final .so which is visible via `scanelf` and `readelf`.  The Android L loader in api mode 23 will flat out refuse to load such an .so.

Questions:
- It this issue to be expected?
- Is there some special declaration to be used on the C or asm side to ensure there are no text relocations?

*Edit*: Would a minimal example be useful?

Comment: Where is the array declared? `.global` would be a declaration, not a reference to an external symbol.

Comment: @Kenney: You seem to confuse declaration and definition.

Comment: The simple solution is to pass a pointer to the array from C/C++ code to your assembly code. The harder one be to use whatever method your platform supports for PIC accesses of global data.

Comment: @Olaf I don't think so. `.global foo` declares symbol foo; `foo:` defines symbol foo. In any case, having `.global foo` 'publicizes' the symbol and adds a relocation entry, whether it is defined in the compilation unit or not. With GNU assembly files you can't declare external symbols.

Comment: @Kenney: Sure you can declare external references. If the symbol is not defined in your source code, it will become an external reference, otherwise it is made externally visible. So, `.global` suits two purposes: make an internal symbol esxternally visible or create an external reference.

Comment: Note there is no language C/C++.

Comment: @Olaf Indeed, if the symbol is not defined, it automatically becomes an external reference - but you can't explicitly declare it as such. And since this is automatic, `.global` or not, `.global` only serves one purpose: to make a symbol externally visible. But, semantics! :-) The thing I wanted to point out is that you DON'T use `.global` to declare a symbol as external, and if that was the intent, it might be the cause of the relocation showing up.

Comment: @Kenney: Not sure what you mean with "if the symbol is not defined ...". Do you mean even without a `.global` declaration, an undefined symbol becomes a external reference? That would be new information for me, but I might have never ran into this. The documentation of gas tells different, I think. But I might be wrong and it is just for the attributes (which might be relevant here, though)

Comment: @Olaf Indeed. `.global` and external references have nothing to do with each other. I've written an OS in assembly using GNU as and ld, so I've run into plenty of such issues. It's actually quite hard to get errors when asm sources reference undefined symbols.

Comment: @Kenney: Hmm, I try to avoid assembler - had enough for my lifetime - now and prefer C (not C++!). Few stubs of inline-assembler are most times sufficient (except for startup code). Ok, found it at the description for `.extern`. That's the curse of writing good code;-): you do not even notice such issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94145/discussion-between-olaf-and-kenney).

Comment: In reply to a bit of everyone, I've attempted every scenario: 1) declaring the array in C++ as `extern "C" int16_t *myarray;` and actually "storing it" if you will in asm using something like: `myarray: .skip 256` and of course the `.global myarray`.   2) declaring it in C++ as per my original post above.

Comment: Define the array in C++ code. Pass a pointer to it as an argument in a function call from your C++ code to your assembly code. Do not store the argument in a global variable in your assembly code. Keep it in a register or on the stack. That way you won't be accessing a data symbol in your assembly code and won't have a relocation.

Comment: hmmm.. smart cookie you are.  Will test.

Comment: See: [the question 'how to access data from PIC code on ARM.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351001/how-to-access-data-from-position-independent-code-pic-in-arm-assembly).  Either is a duplicate or this question is currently too broad.  I would try `-msingle-pic-base`.

Comment: The pointer trick worked (no more complaints of text relocation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all the comments.  So to summarize for the good of everyone else fighting with Android M, we were able to solve some of our issues.  My understanding now is as follows and please, correct me if I am wrong:

1) I could not in asm point to directly to an external globals (i.e. ldr) without causing a text relocation.

2) I could not in asm reference a symbol contained in data section even if not global, because the relative address from text to data is unknown at assembly time.   Why the .so linker cannot resolve this at link time I am not sure, but I can only assume the relative address is too far or by nature of PIC the relative addresses of data/text aren't known at run-time (?).

So our fix was:

1) Pre-generate the arrays and add to the text section, as close as possible to the code using it (relative instructions have a limited distance).  We found that putting the table too far from the code using it failed.

2) Use of 'adr' is preferred of 'ldr' when loading from a label as it seemed to ensure you're loading from the current section and helped us avoid some text relocations

Fortunately our arrays were static data though generated at runtime and could be converted to const known at assembly time.  But for those where the array or memory is dynamic and must be passed from C to asm, I see no other choice put to pass it as a parameter to the assembly code as suggested by several people in the comments.

A useful read was: [ARM - Loading addresses into registers](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0040d/Bgbbihdc.html)

Comment: So another solution was kind of weak but less weak than duplicating the array, and would also work for non-const arrays:

1) Define a getter method in C that returns the array
2) Call this method from ASM.  In this case, the method called is (usually) in the same section as the asm code and thus no relocation occurs.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below code, it works for me

//=======================================================

file: asm.s

```
.globl asm_test

.LglobalInt:
    .int    globalInt-.

asm_test:
    push {LR}

    // change the value of globalInt variable
    LDR r1, .LglobalInt
    adr r2, .LglobalInt
    add r0, r1, r2
    ldr r1, =123456789
    STR r1, [r0]

    pop {LR}
    bx lr
```

//=======================================================

file: test.c

```
int globalInt = 0;

int main()
{
    printf("globalInt = %d\n", globalInt);
    asm_test();
    printf("globalInt = %d\n", globalInt);
}
```